# openssl Verify return code 7 (certificate signature failure)

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created my own CA and an Intermediate CA
The Intermediate CA is signed from the self-signed CA and then I create a private key and a certificate for the web sites I have in my lab. The certificate has as common name the FQDN of the server (which is the same as the CA/IntCA).
The certificate has all the sites in the Subject Alternative Names.

Apache is configured like this for all sites:

```
# HTTP
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName trd.example.com
  # Redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# Logging
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog logs/trd.example.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/trd.example.com-access_log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName trd.example.com

  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/private/server.example.com_key.pem
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.example.com_chain.pem

  Protocols h2 http/1.1
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

  SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 

  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/trd

  # Logging
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog logs/trd.example.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/trd.example.com-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The file `server.example.com_chain.pem` contains the site's certificate and the Intermediate's CA certificate. Apache starts, but then, when I connect to any site either with Firefox or Chrome, I get SSL errors.
I tried to verify the ssl with the openssl command and I get this error:

```
Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
```

The full output of the command is:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect trd.example.com:443   
openssl s_client -connect trd.example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
verify return:1
depth=1 C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
verify return:1
depth=0 C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
verify error:num=7:certificate signature failure
verify return:1
depth=0 C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
   i:C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
 1 s:C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
   i:C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEuzCCBB2gAwIBAgIUXaYFIVHY33EeSst3A22ExUzKjf8wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
....
MQhgl8SAmayZK81mLpvO7SoUEjOUYyKzht08qjSJACDwGhFL5YuXydWcuTDPN+tv
CzYVuHq/HJcX8zocGzhz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com

issuer=C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3566 bytes and written 396 bytes
Verification error: certificate signature failure
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 6999AE5E768A5068199C8AEC33395E11CAA6CD9A9AA00952C4EDED9FB14A6DCA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: F09B2927E48D9934395D9FB1364D70DE798EF30694687B0918B4517F8BD2B83E70FDA60640C9165FAF19EE81DAD97C03
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 27 c8 f4 bd 54 77 e3 70-9a 22 1e 9a 85 c6 07 92   '...Tw.p."......
    0010 - 61 0c f4 33 53 aa 62 ba-ff fe a9 84 3f c6 35 32   a..3S.b.....?.52
    0020 - 1b 70 e8 5e 67 ad 82 b0-70 a4 da 20 ae 18 8e ef   .p.^g...p.. ....
    0030 - bf b1 cf f6 1b ea 1d 4d-9e eb 8d 9f 80 ee 66 93   .......M......f.
    0040 - a7 5e 53 54 a9 89 6e 5a-59 62 cc ac d6 90 91 1e   .^ST..nZYb......
    0050 - 3f db 75 f0 5c f9 72 3c-a3 8b c9 77 16 9f bf 4d   ?.u.\.r<...w...M
    0060 - ae 65 5a 5e 05 ae 84 45-8b 48 f7 a8 99 08 c1 c0   .eZ^...E.H......
    0070 - d0 66 3f 54 c6 1f ca e3-1d a6 50 22 ab 92 80 c8   .f?T......P"....
    0080 - 7f f5 be 6a 4d 4d 0a 7a-e6 82 6d e0 e6 72 32 e2   ...jMM.z..m..r2.
    0090 - d4 ab e2 2a ea cb 00 83-c7 51 de 7c c3 52 1a 5e   ...*.....Q.|.R.^
    00a0 - 94 3e 38 81 cb 05 27 6e-0a f0 5d 32 27 ea 5f c4   .>8...'n..]2'._.
    00b0 - 50 de b0 12 69 6a 3b 4f-ae cc 85 64 a2 93 1a b0   P...ij;O...d....
    00c0 - 7d 60 04 6c a3 4b 3c de-7c 08 04 b1 8b 1f 53 d4   }`.l.K<.|.....S.
    00d0 - 1e db 57 ca 08 f8 0c 8a-45 84 fe a7 f4 eb 88 2c   ..W.....E......,
    00e0 - 90 f5 96 f1 6a c4 54 eb-16 54 86 6c 9f bc b8 52   ....j.T..T.l...R

    Start Time: 1585135481
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 844AB89D046A9564B4F71DE1689D63E295D796AA3DB3C97360A276216A711052
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 10DBA6252AECC4DC7A9567DA8CDA7C4B6695E0788D33533F155726628A8CBE9DC361A977473759402A9E2D2EA15698A7
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 27 c8 f4 bd 54 77 e3 70-9a 22 1e 9a 85 c6 07 92   '...Tw.p."......
    0010 - 7b f3 f1 29 8d 79 74 0f-43 bc f1 40 70 16 52 99   {..).yt.C..@p.R.
    0020 - 78 6f e8 14 bc 4b 34 f8-7f 03 1c 26 70 6f d9 94   xo...K4....&po..
    0030 - 92 e7 b4 b2 19 68 37 95-1e ab fa 42 ea ee de 4c   .....h7....B...L
    0040 - 45 da 86 c5 db 30 1a 60-91 85 d5 9e 05 0b e4 5f   E....0.`......._
    0050 - 5e eb c8 b8 94 f5 e0 a5-01 1c 60 cc 7c a0 bc 70   ^.........`.|..p
    0060 - 10 55 c7 48 1c 2a 2b 57-06 ad dc b9 c1 56 e7 34   .U.H.*+W.....V.4
    0070 - 4b bd 59 67 ad f0 d7 55-a3 07 26 10 7f c5 4f 87   K.Yg...U..&...O.
    0080 - 96 7f 43 bf 8c 1b f5 84-37 f5 47 99 c7 8e a4 29   ..C.....7.G....)
    0090 - 9f b6 43 79 43 27 04 33-7c 5d 2a ef cf 2c 15 1d   ..CyC'.3|]*..,..
    00a0 - 14 d0 a3 a1 4b ef c2 a2-02 c5 4c 75 74 08 d5 cf   ....K.....Lut...
    00b0 - 47 cc 02 fb a3 c2 e0 d8-87 ad e1 3b c6 f4 d6 aa   G..........;....
    00c0 - e6 cb a1 a8 6c e9 c9 e8-56 0a bf d4 3e fa 08 a0   ....l...V...>...
    00d0 - 26 02 82 36 33 71 db 9f-bf ce b8 8f d7 ef 75 b3   &..63q........u.
    00e0 - fb d1 38 56 81 b0 ed f6-c6 35 66 e3 87 bd 68 d9   ..8V.....5f...h.

    Start Time: 1585135481
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
```

This is my chain certificate:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -subject -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.example.com_chain.pem 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            5d:a6:05:21:51:d8:df:71:1e:4a:cb:77:03:6d:84:c5:4c:ca:8d:ff
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 24 16:42:09 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jan 15 11:00:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:eb:a7:c3:a0:23:d6:7a:ac:fb:4c:70:e1:cf:b9:
                    f2:4d:ff:d8:ed:9d:40:cb:e4:68:67:b0:02:d2:25:
                    03:15:37:18:31:e0:90:7f:2c:ff:dd:ef:da:64:9d:
                    e8:86:48:b3:75:9b:a7:8e:b2:70:e2:fb:d0:c3:b3:
                    74:42:52:57:65:35:db:0e:4f:57:57:a6:3c:ee:7b:
                    33:7d:1d:0e:25:e0:4a:eb:26:0c:f3:2b:04:23:c5:
                    6c:c0:95:0b:06:61:33:7d:ca:be:c3:b9:fa:f0:b2:
                    01:eb:9d:55:8d:cb:1f:3c:96:78:6a:8b:9e:66:9c:
                    26:6b:fa:8a:d9:2a:2c:3a:bf:73:97:78:4b:a8:6f:
                    41:7f:0a:f0:4a:63:e5:92:ca:f8:f8:7b:cf:0c:b2:
                    f3:7c:4d:ca:75:ed:0a:b2:99:f0:75:e0:7c:9f:e7:
                    b5:53:9a:08:3d:71:5d:f6:39:91:85:1e:47:04:0f:
                    5a:a2:26:b5:5f:4e:2d:d9:95:3b:32:88:b8:f4:54:
                    5e:1e:64:11:cd:cb:3c:17:4d:d3:a5:c7:bb:88:1c:
                    01:db:43:ee:b8:16:f8:95:c8:37:96:de:c1:3e:cd:
                    a9:f9:7c:f6:94:fb:a6:6d:67:9d:69:24:0b:0e:43:
                    b2:94:6d:54:61:04:41:c3:e9:ed:0f:80:e8:3b:69:
                    ca:f2:76:39:7b:f6:6c:48:4c:94:0a:cc:57:50:14:
                    1e:c7:7f:c7:b5:98:e7:50:a7:ea:f8:9b:73:ad:77:
                    be:ab:2d:7b:e6:c3:e8:2b:8a:bd:3b:26:b3:7b:a0:
                    4f:90:96:6e:92:50:d5:8c:a0:5a:c8:2e:9f:82:52:
                    35:82:f5:5d:0e:e8:fb:89:f2:b3:ef:85:ae:ae:fe:
                    ea:52:75:2e:dd:ad:a5:a2:ff:2d:22:df:8c:50:39:
                    f6:d1:30:8b:73:c9:a5:da:d6:28:96:db:9b:55:d7:
                    bd:30:fc:ec:3e:3c:10:94:9f:05:39:63:1c:2d:37:
                    56:d5:33:ed:cc:5d:d6:0c:df:57:2b:9c:07:35:8e:
                    20:74:9f:53:09:08:32:26:a8:11:e8:6e:98:d4:a3:
                    b9:4a:40:28:5b:e0:9d:41:2a:07:bc:cd:fb:2a:6c:
                    fb:cd:55:c8:fa:a9:7b:68:76:bb:79:58:30:96:97:
                    c1:db:b3:fe:b6:05:94:bf:a7:49:03:9f:e8:fe:b0:
                    88:6f:3f:52:a9:ac:86:72:df:20:19:df:80:76:85:
                    72:0e:a6:d5:fe:34:b6:21:d4:19:5e:c1:96:c0:ca:
                    58:da:69:f8:41:07:66:17:98:bf:62:0b:97:c1:fa:
                    f1:39:a1:df:13:0f:8f:15:9f:e0:d0:04:6e:38:50:
                    51:2a:27
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
                DNS: server.example.com, DNS: db.example.com, DNS: trd.example.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:81:87:02:42:01:15:65:da:1f:05:77:50:36:05:6f:06:17:
         85:aa:29:9b:12:e0:ae:c6:75:03:71:c2:b5:19:a4:57:35:43:
         ca:28:a5:54:87:3f:a1:69:c8:8d:67:dd:8f:d5:78:e5:f3:40:
         ba:09:24:4c:db:3e:e5:9e:c0:65:05:94:07:a9:29:e6:d1:02:
         41:37:da:31:08:60:97:c4:80:99:ac:99:2b:cd:66:2e:9b:ce:
         ed:2a:14:12:33:94:63:22:b3:86:dd:3c:aa:34:89:00:20:f0:
         1a:11:4b:e5:8b:97:c9:d5:9c:b9:30:cf:37:eb:6f:0b:36:15:
         b8:7a:bf:1c:97:17:f3:3a:1c:1b:38:73
subject=C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = server.example.com, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
```

And this is the certificate of my CA:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -subject -in /etc/pki/ca/certs/MyCA_crt.pem 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            71:....:19:90:e4
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 24 09:33:34 2020 GMT
            Not After : Mar  1 11:00:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:...:61
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS: server.example.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         09:...29
subject=C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = ...
```

And this is the CA1 certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            47:d8:98:93:...:92:75:15:c2:cf:20:13
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 24 09:33:37 2020 GMT
            Not After : Feb  1 11:00:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9e:e4:fd:a2:d5:73:b9:9a:ed:5c:aa:5a:c8:50:
                    9d:66:b1:0c:43:d3:33:72:5a:32:95:b9:fb:70:fa:
                    ...
                    0a:b8:83:f2:d2:02:91:8b:f9:40:6d:5d:ab:21:b7:
                    79:4a:53:b4:b4:d2:c7:e3:ac:bb:64:25:1a:90:07:
                    eb:fe:22:ba:d3:98:33:d9:18:5b:8f:0d:52:0d:02:
                    20:57:61
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS: server.example.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8d:27:2a:ed:eb:7b:dc:35:d2:65:10:58:1b:71:a4:d9:73:28:
         06:8d:b5:ae:25:0c:29:e1:8c:7c:4f:3b:44:2d:05:d6:d8:ee:
         c4:47:c2:4f:15:57:59:95:85:0b:78:d0:95:43:9d:1c:29:40:
         5a:46:72:a0:88:95:18:98:5c:b2:61:9c:fc:05:67:a0:b0:a4:
         ...
         d8:b9:c7:7a:ed:fa:47:46:72:a7:ce:bf:9a:64:c2:2f:b7:7f:
         d5:9a:a1:73:d2:bb:b2:55:2d:fb:ef:7c:1d:4e:89:07:8d:9b:
         81:98:fa:50:ec:8c:63:e5
subject=C = UN, ST = Locality, L = City, O = MyCompany LTD, OU = IT, CN = myCA1, emailAddress = hostmaster@example.com
```

How can I find what is wrong with it???

The full certificate chain is the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF9jCCA96gAwIBAgIUR9iYk/cYS7UPoZ9vd5J1FcLPIBMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwgZMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdSMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZBdHRpY2ExFTATBgNVBAcMDEFy
Z3lyb3Vwb2xpczEdMBsGA1UECgwUUGV0ZXIgVHNlbGlvcyAtIEhvbWUxCzAJBgNV
BAsMAklUMRAwDgYDVQQDDAdob21lLUNBMR4wHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg9ob3N0bWFz
dGVyQGhvbWUwHhcNMjAwMzI0MDkzMzM3WhcNMzAwMjAxMTEwMDAwWjCBlDELMAkG
A1UEBhMCR1IxDzANBgNVBAgMBkF0dGljYTEVMBMGA1UEBwwMQXJneXJvdXBvbGlz
MR0wGwYDVQQKDBRQZXRlciBUc2VsaW9zIC0gSG9tZTELMAkGA1UECwwCSVQxETAP
BgNVBAMMCGhvbWUtQ0ExMR4wHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg9ob3N0bWFzdGVyQGhvbWUw
ggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQCe5P2i1XO5mu1cqlrIUJ1m
sQxD0zNyWjKVuftw+naem4fRw0IhFCFeB4dy9sAN3UsByT0FbFxqs5Z2GvNjTtIz
o+zeARI7H5sd0Hym6BiNqteglywwGDe19swT00D0rfNAfuhGIBgCICrKyPHe6b8Z
sFOwWTRy4FA1HI7b4KXkQvSSt/dGD5gzaa/Ase3ayCEdutrCH+5FXazHZTUVculT
gAqbA9zYHOnKUm5D1L+qzfV2jOpn1+FNF4JVpl3EdkLXdx9tmGEVFfwD8n60Mb3b
istCfRBX4SN7MZyqeflmYUfJI2vBQO1dbhC1E2lFbCSmyaxItw5dABZQWKoSql6g
q1ExPCC6WgX7+hsfIlA10hceI465OoKCk2JbtbWTcEZAlUZw9zk98EAReg2inA1Q
U8D2sz+Q+uZay74uEt11fY/cKIrjTkvusVj/YxmBbSvcpoiaX1Ru8NsiNH7wUpRd
qC+xDlCTmAnH9lQpMrPK2iHVTKx69PThCpfM5VW6OurQLDYqmoNh2EMhDUsH+IPY
oREIUi52mQRHHql2m1m7T39UyllCJN4C54FFqdaEi+hAQ1mc707bYw/OcNrH8vis
X1xwHw7Q9nWZJPHcED7Eiwq4g/LSApGL+UBtXasht3lKU7S00sfjrLtkJRqQB+v+
IrrTmDPZGFuPDVINAiBXYQIDAQABoz8wPTAXBgNVHREEEDAOggwgc2VydmVyLmhv
bWUwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQELBQADggIBAI0nKu3re9w10mUQWBtxpNlzKAaNta4lDCnhjHxPO0QtBdbY7sRH
wk8VV1mVhQt40JVDnRwpQFpGcqCIlRiYXLJhnPwFZ6CwpKde37l2jyXEvORKbN/p
BTaRX7gD8KUM9ambzYhcX6zKhJkF6wxigBstUWGGiVcDg51gGS7TvahqzMlDY1e5
mARMYnQdSQN6mBonvjHo0vo5vY4f6aHCxLQpMkpGOstCShHKCUTF+dU98XDvWyEL
Yxk3XwuXb6TltjPM7Y/9BrRlhj8lGjOTJzXReR7pvikPCZFIi6clwuUjE+QzmVda
2wLzk3YSrJRpbFZWf5Zt69nl0D3pG/HQLFTBLZxlvYndB2jQw+yuRwdaY+m3b4bb
UXP6kk00QQEcCiROJ73tmT2RQ2sRLDL6vnPVxWQeWq9nfiXCQR9N8R6yK0Sb6x0C
6yvgyVm6MFxqY7rPCrkiKMkz4ZnN4f03Ri258UFCZnlNs3KvTQ1AoqYVLOKzwe0M
o6YroN411dikyiEOcUH4IbY3i/Nof8udRHIlexTrwWne0o88XXeNydGnAQ3qQajh
WPe34cOGeh7eIa0n4fzmt5/LaLUJzp8RGPNGiUIu7c+D+Hm3NKiciKwZOOtY49i5
x3rt+kdGcqfOv5pkwi+3f9WaoXPSu7JVLfvvfB1OiQeNm4GY+lDsjGPl
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So, how can I find what is wrong with my certificates?

Comment: According to your output both the server certificate (server.example.com) and the intermediate CA (myCA1) are issued by the root CA (myCA). This is contrary to your claim that the server.example.com is issued by myCA1 (and not myCA).

Comment: Correct. I fixed it and I have the same problem again. 
What I did was: 
Delete the chain certificate file
Delete the server's certificate
Sign the CSR with the correct key. 

Still the same issue

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state then so that one has sufficient details what is really going on instead of just blindly guessing what the output after your latest changes might be.

Comment: Updated port with the new certificates

Comment: I cannot see anything obvious right now. Would it be possible to provide the exact certificates as PEM instead of only text (or other certificates which exhibit the same problems) so that one can actually reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes. I will update the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how you've created the certificates. But the certificate CA1 was not used to sign the leaf certificate, something else was used.

Details: the public key of the shown intermediate certificate CA1 is an RSA key. Thish means that the signature algorithm for the server certificate must be `sha256WithRSAEncryption` or similar. But, as can be seen from your question it is actually `ecdsa-with-SHA256`. This means that the leaf certificate was signed with ECDSA (certificate with ECC public key) and not with RSA (certificate RSA public key). In other words: since the type does not match it could not have ben signed by the shown certificate for CA1.

Comment: Now I am confused. 
Because I recreated the CA and the CA1 when I discovered that Chrome doesn't support ECC keys of 521bytes length...

I think I will delete everything and start from scratch.

Comment: I found the problem, eventually. 
So, I created an ECC private key for the CA and CA1. 
However, Chrome doesn't support the 521 keys, so, I reverted back to the RSA4096. 

BUT, the csr of the CA1 was regenerated based on the OLD key! 
Big mess.